# How to pass image from html to php through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, image

```
function UpdateUserDetails() 
{
   var title = $("#title1").val();
   var store = $(".search-box").val();
   var category= $("#category").val();
   var descp=$("#descp1").val();
   var price=$("#price1").val();
   var value=$("#value1").val();
   var location=$("#location1").val();
   var url=$("#url1").val();
   var id = $("#hidden_user_id").val();

   $.post("update.php", {
        id: id,
        title:title,
        store:store,
        category:category,
        descp:descp,
        price:price,
        value:value,
        location:location,
        url:url

    },
    function (data, status) {
        $("#update_user_modal").modal("hide");
    }
);
}
```

The above is my code where it fetches values from html form and then sends to update.php file. How can i send a image file through this function along with all the variables? should i send it as file itself or by encoding it? Help me out!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: try to search by byte array image ajax, sure something exists.

Comment: can u edit the above code with sample image variable? @roberto06

Answer (score 0):

Very basic approach is:

1. Convert image to base64-data [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)
2. Send it via ajax as string and on server side just `base64_decode($b64Image)` and save raw data to file

But don't forget to set **post_max_size** in **php.ini** and/or in Nginx body_size (i forget how it named)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData to pass files to your php file through ajax. For example:

```
$(':file').change(function() {
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery(':file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file[]', file);
});
```

Then you can send it by ajax:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
       //your code
    }
});
```

Now you can treat these files like $_FILES['file'] array on your php.